# Handling User Defined shaders in OpenGL ES 2.0 framework

Tags: opengl-es, shader, user-defined

I am developing a frame-based animation framework in OpenGL ES 2.0 to develop 3D graphics applications.

I have used few pre-defined shaders (for color, texture, alpha....) whose attributes and uniform are known.

Now I want to handle user given shaders. Loading, compiling and linking these shaders are fine.
But how to map the attributes and uniforms to its corresponding data.

Suppose, in the user given shader, the vertex data has to be passed to attribute **"a_vertex"**.
In some other shader, it may be **"a_myVertex"**.
Thus name of the attribute to pass vertex data will be different for different user given shaders.

My question is how to handle the mapping of shader attributes and uniforms in the user given shaders.

Please give some suggestions to do this.

Thanks...

Comment: If the user is creating their own attribute names, then you're going to have to ask them to specify what the attributes represent. So then you can just do a string replace on their shader code before compiling it.

Comment: A string replace can be very dangerous. Consider something like uniform vec2 texCoord; uniform textCoord2; now do a string replace on texCoord in the shader.

Comment: Anyway this should generally not be done at all. When creating shaders and a client using them there should be some communication on how the parameters should be named. If it is in your power you should set some standards for everyone to use same names for common uniforms and attributes. If this are shaders pasted from the web you best know you should go through every shader and triple check what and how it does stuff so in the process you can also rename the parameters to make sense.